# Simplifying $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}ne^{-a}\frac{a^{x+n}}{(x+n)!}$, where $x$ is an integer and $a<1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I would like to simplify the following expression,

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}ne^{-a}\frac{a^{x+n}}{(x+n)!}$$

where $x$ is an integer and $a<1$.

Is it possible to lose the sum?

An approximation for the sum will be also helpful.

Comment: presumably $x$ is an integer?

Comment: Yes @Seth thanks.

Comment: you can bring out the $a^x$ factor and also $1/x!$

Comment: Thanks @phdmba7of12 but what with the sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum can be written as
$$
\eqalign{
  & S(a,x) = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {ne^{\, - \,a} {{a^{\,x + n} } \over {\left( {x + n} \right)!}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = e^{\, - \,a} \sum\limits_{k = x}^\infty  {\left( {k - x} \right){{a^{\,k} } \over {k!}}}  = e^{\, - \,a} \left( {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty
  {\left( {k - x} \right){{a^{\,k} } \over {k!}}}  - \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{x - 1} {\left( {k - x} \right){{a^{\,k} } \over {k!}}} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = e^{\, - \,a} \left( {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {k{{a^{\,k} } \over {k!}}}  - x\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {{{a^{\,k} } \over {k!}}}
  - \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{x - 1} {k{{a^{\,k} } \over {k!}}}  + x\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{x - 1} {{{a^{\,k} } \over {k!}}} } \right) \cr} 
$$

Since 
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  e^{\, - \,a} \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{x - 1} {{{a^{\,k} } \over {k!}}}  = {{\Gamma (x,a)} \over {\Gamma (x)}} = Q(x,a) \hfill \cr 
  \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {k{{a^{\,k} } \over {k!}}}  = a{d \over {da}}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {{{a^{\,k} } \over {k!}}}  = ae^{\,\,a}  \hfill \cr 
  \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{x - 1} {k{{a^{\,k} } \over {k!}}}  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{x - 1} {{{a^{\,k} } \over {\left( {k - 1} \right)!}}}
  = a\sum\limits_{j = 0}^{x - 2} {{{a^{\,j} } \over {j!}}}  = ae^{\,\,a} Q(x - 1,a) \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

where $Q(x,a)$ is the [Regularized Incomplete Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Regularized_Gamma_functions_and_Poisson_random_variables) function,
it is easy to conclude.

Another way is
$$
\eqalign{
  & S(a,x) = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {ne^{\, - \,a} {{a^{\,x + n} } \over {\left( {x + n} \right)!}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = e^{\, - \,a} \left( {\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\left( {n + x} \right){{a^{\,x + n} } \over {\left( {x + n} \right)!}}}
  - x\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{{a^{\,x + n} } \over {\left( {x + n} \right)!}}} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = e^{\, - \,a} \left( {a\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{{a^{\,x + n - 1} } \over {\left( {x + n - 1} \right)!}}}
  - x\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{{a^{\,x + n} } \over {\left( {x + n} \right)!}}} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = e^{\, - \,a} \left( {a\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{{a^{\,\left( {x - 1} \right) + n} } \over {\left( {\left( {x - 1} \right) + n} \right)!}}}
  - x\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{{a^{\,\left( {x - 1} \right) + n + 1} } \over {\left( {\left( {x - 1} \right) + n + 1} \right)!}}} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = e^{\, - \,a} \left( {a\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{{a^{\,\left( {x - 1} \right) + n} } \over {\left( {\left( {x - 1} \right) + n} \right)!}}}
  - x\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{{a^{\,\left( {x - 1} \right) + n} } \over {\left( {\left( {x - 1} \right) + n} \right)!}}} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = e^{\, - \,a} \left( {a{{a^{\,\left( {x - 1} \right)} } \over {\left( {x - 1} \right)!}} + a\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{{a^{\,\left( {x - 1} \right) + n} }
 \over {\left( {\left( {x - 1} \right) + n} \right)!}}}
  - x\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{{a^{\,\left( {x - 1} \right) + n} } \over {\left( {\left( {x - 1} \right) + n} \right)!}}} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = e^{\, - \,a} \left( {a{{a^{\,\left( {x - 1} \right)} } \over {\left( {x - 1} \right)!}}
 + \left( {a - x} \right)\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{{a^{\,x + n} } \over {\left( {x + n} \right)!}}} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = e^{\, - \,a} \left( {a{{a^{\,\left( {x - 1} \right)} } \over {\left( {x - 1} \right)!}}
 + \left( {a - x} \right)\sum\limits_{k = x}^\infty  {{{a^{\,k} } \over {k!}}} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = e^{\, - \,a} \left( {a{{a^{\,\left( {x - 1} \right)} } \over {\left( {x - 1} \right)!}} + \left( {a - x} \right)\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {{{a^{\,k} } \over {k!}}}
  - \left( {a - x} \right)\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{x - 1} {{{a^{\,k} } \over {k!}}} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = e^{\, - \,a} {{a^{\,x} } \over {\left( {x - 1} \right)!}} + \left( {a - x} \right)
 - \left( {a - x} \right)e^{\, - \,a} \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{x - 1} {{{a^{\,k} } \over {k!}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = e^{\, - \,a} {{a^{\,x} } \over {\Gamma (x)}} + \left( {a - x} \right)\left( {1 - Q(x,a)} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = e^{\, - \,a} {{a^{\,x} } \over {\Gamma (x)}} + \left( {a - x} \right){{\gamma (x,a)} \over {\Gamma (x)}} \cr} 
$$
which *checks with the previous one*.

*---  Addendum ---*

Concerning your comment and the request for a nice approximation to the sum $S(a,x)$,
it is not much clear what you intend / need to do. In any case consider the following:
 - the formula above (1st and 2nd way lead to the same result) is valid for $a$ and $c$
real or even complex ( with some  limitations);
 - if $x$ is an integer as you say, then for small values of it the expression in the last-but-third line
is easily computable;
 - if $x$ is large ,  we can apply to $\Gamma(x)$ and $Q(x,a)$ the known asymptotic expansions
which are
$$
\eqalign{
  & \Gamma (x) = \sqrt {\,{{2\,\pi } \over x}\,} \left( {{x \over e}} \right)^{\,x} \left( {1 + O\left( {{1 \over x}} \right)} \right)
\quad \left| {\;x\, \to \,\infty ,\;\;\left| {\,\arg (x)\,} \right|} \right. < \pi   \cr 
  & Q(x,a) \approx 1 - {{x^{\, - x - 1/2} e^{\,x - a} a^{\,x} } \over {\sqrt {2\pi } }}\left( {1 + {{12a - 1} \over {12x}}
 + O\left( {{1 \over {x^{\,2} }}} \right)} \right)\;\quad \left| {\,\left| x \right|\; \to \;\infty } \right.  \cr 
  & Q(x,a) \approx Q(x,1) - {{e^{\, - 1} } \over {\Gamma (x)}}\left( {a - 1} \right) - {{e^{\, - 1} \left( {x - 2} \right)} \over {2\Gamma (x)}}
\left( {a - 1} \right)^{\,2}  + O\left( {\left( {a - 1} \right)^{\,3} } \right)\;\quad \left| {\,\left| a \right|\; \to \;1} \right. \cr} 
$$

Comment: Thanks @G Cab. Is it possible to use Taylor here somehow?

Comment: do you mean a Taylor in $x$ ?

Comment: sorry there was a typo, corrected.

Comment: @G Cab, first of all big thank you! the lest term is beautiful. Intuitively though I was expecting the use of Taylor, and yes Taylor in $x$. Maybe there is a nice approximation for the last sum in your last a expression?

Comment: @Y.L: I added in the answer some considerations about this request. You should be more explicit about the values of $x$ and $a$ around which you want to develop in series.

Comment: @G cab, it's o.k., your text has been extremely helpful. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Y.L: glad it was helpful !

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty ne^{-a}\frac{a^{x+n}}{(x+n)!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^x}{e^a}\frac{na^n}{(x+n)!}=\frac{a^x}{e^a}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n\frac{n}{(x+n)!};$$
$$\scriptstyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n\frac{n}{(x+n)!}=e^aa^{1 - x} - \frac{e^aa^{1 - x}\Gamma(x + 1, a)}{Γ(x + 1)}- e^axa^{-x}+\frac{e^aa^{-x}\Gamma(x + 1, a)}{\Gamma(x)} + \frac{a}{\Gamma(x + 1)}=e^aa^{1-x}-\frac{e^aa^{1-x}}{x!}\frac{x!}{e^a}\sum_{k=0}^{x}\frac{a^k}{k!}-\frac{e^ax}{a^x}+\frac{e^a}{a^xx!}\sum_{k=0}^{x}\frac{a^k}{k!}+\frac{a}{x!}=e^aa^{1-x}-a^{1-x}\sum_{k=0}^{x}\frac{a^k}{k!}-\frac{e^ax}{a^x}+\frac{e^a}{a^xx!}\sum_{k=0}^{x}\frac{a^k}{k!}+\frac{a}{x!}=e^aa^{1-x}+\left(\frac{e^a}{a^xx!}-a^{1-x}\right)\sum_{k=0}^x\frac{a^k}{k!}-\frac{e^ax}{a^x}+\frac{a}{x!};$$
$$\scriptstyle\frac{a^x}{e^a}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n\frac{n}{(x+n)!}=\frac{a^x}{e^a}\left(e^aa^{1-x}+\left(\frac{e^a}{a^xx!}-a^{1-x}\right)\sum_{k=0}^x\frac{a^k}{k!}-\frac{e^ax}{a^x}+\frac{a}{x!}\right)$$
$$=a+\left(\frac{1}{x!}-\frac{a}{e^a}\right)\sum_{k=0}^x\frac{a^k}{k!}-x+\frac{a^{x+1}}{e^ax!}$$
That's the best I can do, it's a lot of algebra, so you might want to double check, but I think that's as simplified as it can possibley get.

This is not an algebraic function, so it can only really be written in terms of improper integrals or appropriate special functions.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%5Cinfty+ne%5E%7B-a%7D%5Cfrac%7Ba%5E%7Bx%2Bn%7D%7D%7B(x%2Bn)!%7D

Answer (score 0):

Starting from R. Burton's answer, the result could simplify to
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}ne^{-a}\frac{a^{x+n}}{(x+n)!}=\frac{a^{x+1} }{x!}\left((x-a) E_{-x}(a)+e^{-a}\right)+a-x$$ where appears  the [exponential integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).